# How do I write an accumulator to squash an array around a midpoint?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I've got an array of arrays as follows:

```
array([[ 7108.4,  -600. ],
       [ 7101.3,  -500. ],
       [ 7094.3,  -400. ],
       [ 7087.2,  -300. ],
       [ 7080.1,  -200. ],
       [ 7073.1,  -100. ],
       [ 7058.3,   100. ],
       [ 7051.3,   200. ],
       [ 7044.2,   300. ],
       [ 7037.1,   400. ],
       [ 7030.1,   500. ],
       [ 7023. ,   600. ]])
```

This is a list of prices and quantities, with the positive numbers being buys and the negative numbers being sells.

If the current market price is 7050, I want to 'squash' my prices, as follows:

```
array([[ 7108.4,  -600. ],
       [ 7101.3,  -500. ],
       [ 7094.3,  -400. ],
       [ 7087.2,  -300. ],
       [ 7080.1,  -200. ],
       [ 7073.1,  -100. ],
       [ 7050. ,   300. ], # Price & quantity changed here
       [ 7044.2,   300. ],
       [ 7037.1,   400. ],
       [ 7030.1,   500. ],
       [ 7023. ,   600. ]])
```

and and do the same in thing in the other direction, so if the market price were 7085:

```
array([[ 7108.4,  -600. ],
       [ 7101.3,  -500. ],
       [ 7094.3,  -400. ],
       [ 7087.2,  -300. ],
       [ 7085. ,  -300. ], # Price & quantity change here
       [ 7058.3,   100. ],
       [ 7051.3,   200. ],
       [ 7044.2,   300. ],
       [ 7037.1,   400. ],
       [ 7030.1,   500. ],
       [ 7023. ,   600. ]])
```

What's the cleanest way to write such a thing? Ideally, I'd like to write the squashing and the quantity grouping as two separate steps.

Comment: What's the logic? Why only 7051.3 and 7058.3 when you specify 7050?

Comment: Because those prices are above the market price, and we don't want to offer a price above the market price.

Comment: So what about 7073.1, 7080.1, ...?

Comment: In this case, the market price is 7085, so we don't want to offer a price below that. You can tell we're selling because the quantity is negative.

Comment: why 12 rows in the data, and 12+1-2 in the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of operations that are made easier by [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> t = np.array([[ 7108.4,  -600. ],
...        [ 7101.3,  -500. ],
...        [ 7094.3,  -400. ],
...        [ 7087.2,  -300. ],
...        [ 7080.1,  -200. ],
...        [ 7073.1,  -100. ],
...        [ 7058.3,   100. ],
...        [ 7051.3,   200. ],
...        [ 7044.2,   300. ],
...        [ 7037.1,   400. ],
...        [ 7030.1,   500. ],
...        [ 7023. ,   600. ]])
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(t, columns=['price', 'quantity'])
>>> (df.price > 7050) & (df.quantity > 0)
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6      True
7      True
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
dtype: bool
>>> df[(df.price > 7050) & (df.quantity > 0)]
    price  quantity
6  7058.3     100.0
7  7051.3     200.0
>>> df[(df.price > 7050) & (df.quantity > 0)].quantity.sum()
300.0
>>> df[(df.price < 7085) & (df.quantity < 0)]
    price  quantity
4  7080.1    -200.0
5  7073.1    -100.0
>>> df[(df.price < 7085) & (df.quantity < 0)].quantity.sum()
-300.0
```

You could still stick with `numpy` if you want:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> t = np.array([[ 7108.4,  -600. ],
...        [ 7101.3,  -500. ],
...        [ 7094.3,  -400. ],
...        [ 7087.2,  -300. ],
...        [ 7080.1,  -200. ],
...        [ 7073.1,  -100. ],
...        [ 7058.3,   100. ],
...        [ 7051.3,   200. ],
...        [ 7044.2,   300. ],
...        [ 7037.1,   400. ],
...        [ 7030.1,   500. ],
...        [ 7023. ,   600. ]])
>>> 
>>> 
>>> t[:,0]
array([ 7108.4,  7101.3,  7094.3,  7087.2,  7080.1,  7073.1,  7058.3,
        7051.3,  7044.2,  7037.1,  7030.1,  7023. ])
>>> t[:,0] > 7050
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,
       False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> (t[:,0] > 7050) & (t[:,1] > 0)
array([False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False,
       False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> t[(t[:,0] > 7050) & (t[:,1] > 0)]
array([[ 7058.3,   100. ],
       [ 7051.3,   200. ]])
>>> t[(t[:,0] < 7085) & (t[:,1] < 0)]
array([[ 7080.1,  -200. ],
       [ 7073.1,  -100. ]])
>>> t[(t[:,0] < 7085) & (t[:,1] < 0)][:,1]
array([-200., -100.])
>>> t[(t[:,0] < 7085) & (t[:,1] < 0)][:,1].sum()
-300.0
```

Comment: That's a good idea. Can I do an assignment here, and then return it back to the original np format?

Comment: @cjm2671: It would mostly be for convenience and naming columns. If you want to stay in `np`, you can too.

Comment: So actually what you did with numpy was my original implementation exactly, however I couldn't then do the final assignment on the original array. Is possible to modify the original array, so that the output is the full list of orders with changes inside?

Answer (score 0):

since Eric answer is great but as per your comment :

> Is possible to modify the original array, so that the output is the
>   full list of orders with changes inside?

Here is my approach without numpy :

```
array=[[ 7108.4,  -600. ],
       [ 7101.3,  -500. ],
       [ 7094.3,  -400. ],
       [ 7087.2,  -300. ],
       [ 7080.1,  -200. ],
       [ 7073.1,  -100. ],
       [ 7058.3,   100. ],
       [ 7051.3,   200. ],
       [ 7044.2,   300. ],
       [ 7037.1,   400. ],
       [ 7030.1,   500. ],
       [ 7023. ,   600. ]]

price=0
positive_value=7050
updated_list=[]
track=[]
for index,item in enumerate(array):
    if item[0]>positive_value:
        if item[1]>0:
            price+=item[1]
            track.append(index)
        else:
            updated_list.append(item)
    else:
        updated_list.append(item)

updated_list.insert(track[0],[positive_value,price])
print(updated_list)
```

output:

```
[[7108.4, -600.0], [7101.3, -500.0], [7094.3, -400.0], [7087.2, -300.0], [7080.1, -200.0], [7073.1, -100.0], [7050, 300.0], [7044.2, 300.0], [7037.1, 400.0], [7030.1, 500.0], [7023.0, 600.0]]
```

for second one:

```
array=[[ 7108.4,  -600. ],
       [ 7101.3,  -500. ],
       [ 7094.3,  -400. ],
       [ 7087.2,  -300. ],
       [ 7080.1,  -200. ],
       [ 7073.1,  -100. ],
       [ 7058.3,   100. ],
       [ 7051.3,   200. ],
       [ 7044.2,   300. ],
       [ 7037.1,   400. ],
       [ 7030.1,   500. ],
       [ 7023. ,   600. ]]

price=0
positive_value=7085
updated_list=[]
track=[]
for index,item in enumerate(array):
    if item[0] < positive_value:
        if item[1] < 0:
            price+=item[1]
            track.append(index)
        else:
            updated_list.append(item)
    else:
        updated_list.append(item)

updated_list.insert(track[0],[positive_value,price])
print(updated_list)
```

output:

```
[[7108.4, -600.0], [7101.3, -500.0], [7094.3, -400.0], [7087.2, -300.0], [7085, -300.0], [7058.3, 100.0], [7051.3, 200.0], [7044.2, 300.0], [7037.1, 400.0], [7030.1, 500.0], [7023.0, 600.0]]
```